# How to show the set F of all finite sequences is connected in the space c0?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Question:
How one can show that the set F of all finite sequences (i.e after n, the entries are zero) is connected in the space c0 (i.e. the space of all sequences that converge to zero)

the metric is sup.

Comment: In which topology?

Answer (score 1):

One approach that may work is to show that $F$ is path-connected, and so connected. In particular, show that if $x,y\in F,$ then $tx+(1-t)y\in F$ for all $t\in[0,1],$ and that the function $[0,1]\to F$ given by $t\mapsto tx+(1-t)y$ is continuous.

Comment: Ah! Yes, you're correct that that works over any topological real vector space. It clearly *doesn't* work over rational vector spaces in general, as $t\mapsto tx+(1-t)y$ will in general not even have such a vector space as a codomain when $x,y$ are distinct, so that may be as nice as it gets. It's possible that it will work for vector spaces over any complete ordered field, but I suspect not (hyperreals, superreals, and surreals providing likely counterexamples). Sorry for the miscues!

Comment: Thanks.  I have little experience with complete ordered fields.  Does such a field necessarily have $\mathbb{R}$ as a subfield somehow?  If so, that would mean that if you allow the field for the vector space to be an arbitrary complete ordered field, the vector space is also a real vector space.  (this is similar to the idea that any complex vector space is a real vector space).

Comment: It *will* work for any (Dedekind-)complete ordered field, since the *only* such field is the real numbers. (I had forgotten this fact.) It looks like we may be able to generalize the notion to vector spaces over arbitrary ordered fields, too, but I'll have to think on it.

Comment: I upvoted your comment because it looks like you found the answer and you put some work into it, but I don't understand it.  The problem is my lack of knowledge.  If I find the time, I'll try to find refererences for the notions of "complete field" and "topological field".

Comment: Let me rephrase, as I was mixing my terminology, yet again. While there is a notion of convexity for vector
spaces over any ordered field (we simply use the $[0,1]$ interval from that field), this does not in
general imply (path-)connectedness as it does in the reals, since only in the reals are intervals connected. Thus, we can only generalize to vector spaces over fields $\Bbb K$ such that $\Bbb K$ is itself is a vector space over $\Bbb R$. Haven't had a chance to work out a proof, yet, but when and if I get to it, I'll let you know.