# Show that the set of all finite sequences $\mathcal{F}$ is connected in the space $c_0$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, analysis

Let

- $\mathcal{F}$ be the space of real sequences $(a_n)_n$ such that  $a_n=0$ $\forall{n}\ge{N}$ for some $N$
- $c_0$ be the space of all real sequences converging to $0$

First of all, I know that this is a duplicate question, it is answered here: [How to show the set F of all finite sequences is connected in the space c0?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/572573/how-to-show-the-set-f-of-all-finite-sequences-is-connected-in-the-space-c0/572614#572614)

But the answer relies on the path-connectedness of $\mathcal{F}$, and regards $\mathcal{F}$ as a space in itself, so it shows that $\mathcal{F}$ is connected in itself, but question asks for connectedness in $c_0$. I want to ask the same question but generalize the concept to the connectedness of subspaces. What about the connectedness of $\mathcal{F}$  in $l_p$ spaces, or in $l_{\infty}$, or even in the space of all sequences? What changes?

For instance, if we assume that the two non-empty sets $A,B$ separates $\mathcal{F}$ in  $c_0$, so that $\bar{A}\cap{B}={A}\cap\bar{B}=\emptyset $, how should we regard the closure? Is it okay to take $x\in{\bar{A}}$ if and only if  $x\in{c_0}$ and $x$ is a closure point to $A$? If we take the closure points of $A$ from the space $\mathcal{F}$ , it seems that the mother space does not change anything,  which seems illogical to me.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you consider the relative topology on the subset, connectedness is intrinsic. In fact, that's the way it is defined. If you had that $\mathcal F$ is not connected on $c_0$, there would exist $A,B\subset c_0$, open, disjoint, and with $\mathcal F\subset A\cup B$. Then $A\cap\mathcal F$ and $B\cap\mathcal F$ would be two relatively open, disjoint subsets of $\mathcal F$ with $\mathcal F=(A\cap\mathcal F)\cup(B\cap\mathcal F)$.